# Turn off computer every day at same time

Tags: shutdown

I want my computer to be turned off every day at 21:30. How do I do this?

I found this command:

```
sudo shutdown -h 21:30
```

Is this correct?

With this I have to have the terminal open all the time. I read that I also can run it in the background so I don't have to have the terminal open all the time. How do I do this?

If I don´t have to run it in the background, what else do I have to do?

Comment: You can setup a cron job.

Comment: How do I do that? I just a beginner with ubuntu.

Comment: You can search "how to setup a cron job".

Answer (score 2):

you can use this;

open cron file;

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/crontab
```

add below end of line

```
30 21 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

Comment: I think it works. But when I try to change the time to test it now I get: ** (gedit:5144): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Instellen van attribuut metadata::gedit-spell-enabled is niet mogelijk

Comment: Sorry, but still does not work. Really I have no clue what I am doing so please help me. When I put in the code and wanted to close the terminal, the code was gone.